# postgresql full text search doesn't find anything when query has derivatives words

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, ruby-on-rails-4

It's the first time I use full text search in postgresql and I have a strange problem. Rails 4 (I don't think Rails is part of my problem) build a sql code like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bookmarks"
WHERE (to_tsvector(title || ' ' || description)
@@ (to_tsquery('english', 'ruby')))
```

It works like a charm with every words but those who have derivatives like **ruby/rubies**

If I search for `designer`, it matches `designer` and `designers`. Fine.
I want `ruby` to match `ruby` and `rubies`. Currently it doesn't match anything, not even `ruby`. What I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to specify `english` as the text configuration to `to_tsquery`, you need to specify it too for `to_tsvector` to get consistent results.

Try with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bookmarks"
WHERE (to_tsvector('english', title || ' ' || description)
@@ (to_tsquery('english', 'ruby')))
```

When `english` is the default text search configuration, `to_tsvector('ruby')` will expand to `'rubi':1` which matches `to_tsquery('english', 'ruby')`

But if the text search configuration is set to something else, it will be expanded differently and won't match.

Example:

```
set default_text_search_config='english';
select to_tsvector('ruby') @@ to_tsquery('english','rubies') as result;
 result 
--------
 t
(1 row)

set default_text_search_config='french';
select to_tsvector('ruby') @@ to_tsquery('english','rubies') as result;
 result 
--------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: There might be something more to it: `select 'rubies designers'::tsvector as a, to_tsvector('rubies designers') as b, to_tsvector('english', 'rubies designers') as c;` -- without `'english'`, pg picks the default dictionary, which is usually english.

Comment: Agreed. I've added an example involving `default_text_search_config` with actual results.

Comment: Feel free to add these two convenience queries too: `with tests as (select 'rubies designers'::tsvector as v1, to_tsvector('rubies designers') as v2, to_tsvector('english', 'rubies designers') as v3, 'ruby'::tsquery as q1, to_tsquery('ruby') as q2, to_tsquery('ruby') as q3) select * from tests;`

Comment: And `with tests as (select 'rubies designers'::tsvector as v1, to_tsvector('rubies designers') as v2, to_tsvector('english', 'rubies designers') as v3, 'ruby'::tsquery as q1, to_tsquery('ruby') as q2, to_tsquery('ruby') as q3) select v1 @@ q1 as v1q1, v2 @@ q1 as v2q1, v3 @@ q1 as v3q1, v1 @@ q2 as v1q2, v2 @@ q2 as v2q2, v3 @@ q2 as v3q2, v1 @@ q3 as v1q3, v2 @@ q3 as v2q3, v3 @@ q3 as v3q3 from tests;`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Now it works as expected. Thanks.